# DynamoDB throws an error when trying to get the item count

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get the total number of items in a Dynamodb table. Given below is the C# code that I use.

```
 context = this.DynamoDBContext;
 var someClassReuslts = context.Scan<SomeClass>(null);
 int itemCount = someClassReuslts .Count<SomeClass>();
```

When I try to execute this it throws below error

> "Unable to convert [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document] of type Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Document to System.String"

Is it a mismatch of a property in the data type of the "SomeClass" Vs the actual items properties in the DB? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue here. I use two different programs to insert data to dynamo db and read data from dynamo db. Both of these programs are supposed to use the same "SomeClass" but unfortunately I had one of the properties altered in the "SomeClass" that I use to read the data (or run the count query) from Dynamo db. Once I fix the data type mismatch. it works fine now.